# Variables are not displayed automatically in Chrome JavaScript debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I worked with the chrome's JavaScript debugger for several months and it worked great. I used the console to display automatically variables' content as they change in real-time without entering them manually.

Last night, the console stopped showing the variables automatically. However, when I enter manually a variable in the console and hit enter, it does show the variable and its content. All other functions are working fine.

Last night Chrome was updated and maybe the two things are related. Can someone check and tell me if he experiences the same problem. If not, can you advise how to fix it. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "stopped showing variables automatically"? Do you mean not seeing the current value in the Watch panel as shown in my example here: http://i.imgur.com/2JpkkYK.png, or simply doing console logs in your code, such as this example: http://i.imgur.com/ka21Yrs.png

Comment: This seems to have started with the latest update to Chrome. A coworker came to me with this problem. Another coworker tried to help, went to look at their settings, and accidentally updated Chrome in the process. After updating the other coworker had this same problem. I'll pst an answer when they figure it out, but for now do not update Chrome! However you probably already did and that's why you're here =(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to the auto complete of variables in the console.
Check the following:

1.Open **DevTools**
2.Press On **Settings**
3.Under **Sources** make sure that *[image]"Autocompletion"* is checked.